# Overflow and contain flex-child of a flex-child

Tags: html, css, vue.js, flexbox, vuetify.js

I am kinda in a dilemma where I have to contain a flex-child of a flex-child not to overflow the parent i.e. not to increase more than the screen height/the height of the parent (which itself is a flex-child)

[Here's](https://codepen.io/adnanchang/pen/qBdOGzj) is the *CodePen* for it.

I have tried to replicate the HTML according to the *Vue* project I am using, and this is more or so the layout I currently have.

**Goal**: The `div` with `class=card-body` which contains a bunch of smaller `v-card` elements is a child of a flex-child itself. I have to make sure it doesn't overflow the screen and gets an overflow instead. I couldn't find something that would help me in this regard. I really dont want to use `calc` because I want `flexbox` to dynamically handle it, if possible.

Here's the HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-app-bar app dense color="primary">
      <v-toolbar-title class="white--text">
        App Title
      </v-toolbar-title>
    </v-app-bar>
    <v-content>
      <div class="d-flex flex-column full-height">
        <!-- TOOLBAR AND SHIZZ -->
        <v-row no-gutters class="flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-1">
          <v-col cols="12">
            <v-toolbar color="secondary" dense>
              <v-toolbar-title class="white--text">
                Some title
              </v-toolbar-title>
            </v-toolbar>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>

<!-- Content -->
          <v-card
    color="column"
    class="d-flex flex-column flex-grow-1 ma-4"
  >
    <v-card-title class="title-1">
      LMAO

      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <!-- Menu Component for column -->
      ICON
    </v-card-title>

    <div
      class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-center card-body ml-3 mr-1"
      :class="$vuetify.theme.dark ? 'card-body-dark' : 'card-body-light'"
    >
      <v-card
        v-for="item in 50"
        :key="item"
        class="mr-4 mb-3"
        :color="$vuetify.theme.dark ? 'card lighten-1' : ''"
      >
        <v-card-text class="title">
          Omae Wa Mou Shindeiru! Omae Wa Mou Shindeiru!
        </v-card-text>
      </v-card>
    </div>
  </v-card>

      </div>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS

```
html,
body {
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.full-height: {
  height: 100% important;
}

.card-body {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website OR off-site example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: How's this: https://codepen.io/haldencollier/pen/poJgyQX

Comment: Hey I added the code, also I checked the link and it still has a scroll bar on the main page and not the body of the 'card'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this with something very simple and I have literally NO IDEA how its working. Honestly speaking it was through trial and error.

All I needed was: `flex-basis: 0`

I have updated the CodePen, you can check it out

Here's the new CSS:

```
html,
body {
    overflow-y: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.full-height {
  height: 100% !important;
}

.card-body {
  overflow-y: auto;
/*   max-height: 100%; */

/*   NEED THIS FOR THE SOLUTION */
  flex-basis: 0;
}
```